# How can I use an external HD to boot from in Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, disk-utility

Recently my OS X Snow Leopard has been taking a really long time to boot up. Suspecting that something might be wrong with the HD I did a disk verification using the Disk Utility. It showed me an error message stating that i need to repair the disk using the disk utility from the installation disk.

However, my CD ROM does not function properly and I am unable to boot from the installation disk.

Is there any way I can use an external HD to boot from?
Any solutions that you could suggest?

[EDIT]
Unfortunately I dont have access to another mac

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac?

Comment: unfortunately I dont have access to another mac

Answer (score 1):

You will need a USB drive (8GB) and access to another Mac or a functioning CD ROM drive. You can use any external drive instead of a USB drive, but be aware that you'll have to format the drive and you'll loose any content on it.

The procedure to make the external HD bootable is explained at [Upgrading to Snow Leopard without optical drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25076/upgrading-to-snow-leopard-without-optical-drive#answer-25083)

Comment: here another nice guide with screenshots http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrading-your-mac-to-snow-leopard-using-your-usb-drive/ :)

Comment: I've made the edit, i dont have access to another mac. Sorry dint mention that earlier. thanks for your answer